# Show button when Video is finished

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube

I am working on the WordPress site , in which I have 2 major plugins installed (i) LearnDash LMS (ii) Elite Video Player

I have created a shortcode from "Elite Video Player" plugin ,  for playing video

and I am placing that shortcode inside Learndash Topic like this : https://prnt.sc/x4nwks

Now Initially I want to hide "Mark Complete" button , and when the video is played completely only then I want to show "Mark Complete" button

I tried various jQuery code , but none of them working

```
var jqueryVideo = jQuery(".video-stream");
jqueryVideo.on("ended", function() {
   alert('This Does Work!');
});
```

Check this image , it is creating blob URL

[image: This is how blob URL is generating]

I also tried this code from this URL : https://github.com/sharan-aithal/Elite-Video-Player  but it is showing 2 videos

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   videoPlayer = jQuery(".Elite_video_player").Video({
      onFinish:jQuery(".learndash_mark_complete_button").show(),
   });
});
```